Modal Verbs for build *Perfekt* in German
I am not sure if this question is better suited for linguistics.SE or German.SE, so please move the question if you feel it fits better there.
In German Verben build their Perfekt (and their Plusquamperfekt as well) with the PPP and either "haben" or "sein":

Ich bin gegangen.
Ich habe gegessen.

Some words can even build the Perfekt with both, although they change their meaning then:

Ich bin gesessen. (I have been sitting.)
Ich habe gesessen. (colloquially for: I was in jail.)

I'd like to know the reason for this and - bonus question - is there any rule by which one can determine which Verb uses which Modalverb?

This phenomenon exists in other languages, such as French (Il est venu = Er ist gekommen) and Early Modern English (He is come). The general characterisation of the verbs that use sein/être/be is similar (intransitive verbs of motion or change) but I don't know if the list of specific verbs is the same in each language. I see that Wiktionary has a list of French verbs that take être, but I can't find a corresponding list of German verbs there. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:French_auxiliary_verbs

@ColinFine The list is not the same in each language, it is not even the same across variants of German.  There are verbs that take haben in one sense and sein in another, and verbs or verb senses that take haben in the North but take sein in the South or in colloquial speech.

The main way to master them is by the good old learning the verb lists an practicing.
This page lists 70 most common sein-verbs grouped into 3 sections: verbs of motion, change of state, and “the other” such verbs. Also note that with the verbs of motion, “sein” is used when the focus is on a change of place. If this is not the focus, you can use both “haben” and “sein” with them, and it's shown with examples at the end of this page.

@YellowSky: I have no problem learning anything - in fact, my German is better than my English. I wanted - and still want - a linguistic reason WHY certain words belong to one or the other group and how it came to pass.

It's well known that the analytical perfect tense developed from free phrases with the PPP in its adjectival meaning, and only later getting grammaticalized and with PPP becoming a part of the verb itself. It's only now that in German just 2 aux. verbs remain, there used to be more of them earlier. Have a look at Chapter 5. The Present Perfect in Old and Middle High German, page 36 in this paper (page 41 in the file), it explains how German Perfekt evolved and you'll see the reasons why it's so now.
